# salt: several minions on one host?

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, docker, salt-stack

Up to now we run our applications in several python virtual environments on one linux host.

We consider to use salt but we want to be able to update one virtualenv without modifying the other virtualenvs.

AFAIK you can say "please go into highstate" only to the complete minion.

We see these solutions:

- run several minions on one linux OS: AFAIK not supported at the moment
- use one minion, but don't use highstate. We need to address each virtualenv with one state (we can't say "highstate" to the whole minion)
- use some sort of virtualization (for example docker) to give each virtualenv one minion.

I am new to salt, please ask if I am missing something our you don't get what I want.

**Update**

We have a lot of virtualenvs per linux OS. And all of them are very equal. We would like to manage them without creating a sls file for each.

Comment: Dear users who vote for closing this question: Please tell me why.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/15145

Answer (score 4):

I think your best bet is to just specify a particular state that targets the virtualenv you want to manage or modify.

```
salt 'minion-id' state.sls manage_virtualenv_1
salt 'minion-id' state.sls manage_virtualenv_flask
salt 'minion-id' state.sls manage_virtualenv_django
```

These three state.sls calls will only run the states in each sls file, even though they all exist on the same host named 'minion-id'

EDIT:

You can also use a comma delimited list of sls files:

```
salt 'minion-id' state.sls manage_virtualenv_1,manage_virtualenv_flask,otherslsfile
```

Comment: Thank you for this hint. But how can I address several states on one minion? Example: I want to update all django sites. AFAIK `salt 'minion-id' state.sls manage_virtualenv_django_*` does not work

Comment: You can pass in a comma separated list of sls files you want to execute:
http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.sls